# TikZ Smith Chart with s2p (touchstone) files

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

I'm trying to plot touchstone (s2p) data exported from another software, but the touchstone coordinate system is rectangular. So I have to overlay a XY plot over the smith chart to get it right.

The XY chart should have the center (0,0) in the center of the smith chart, and range from (-1,-1) to (1,1). 
(0,1) should align at the top of the smith chart.
(0,-1) should align at the bottom the smith chart.
The edges should be at (+/- 1,0).

My fallback for now is the `scikit-rf` from python, but the output graphics is not very nice or configurable. So I would love to have it working in `tikz`.

The example under shows that the two don't overlap properly. Any clue how to make the normal axis environment perfectly overlap the smith chart? ?

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.smithchart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{smithchart}[title=S]
\end{smithchart}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
(-1,0)
(1,0)
(0,-1)
(0,1)
(0,0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please make your code compilable. This is much more useful than a fragment as people don't have to figure out how to complete it and can copy-paste-compile to immediately reproduce the problem.  Right now, your example doesn't *show* anything because nobody but you can compile it. I suspect this will be true even if I were to figure out how to complete it.

Comment: @cfr done!, sorry, didn't think about that.

Comment: Great! And an answer, too ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer by digging in the PGFPLOTS manual, 
Setting the smith chart width, as it is circular to a set value, and setting the height and width of the rectangular plot made everything work out.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.smithchart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{smithchart}[title=S,width=10cm]
\end{smithchart}
\begin{axis}[ymax=1,ymin=-1,xmax=1,xmin=-1,hide axis, height=10cm,width=10cm]
\addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
(-1,0)
(1,0)
(0,-1)
(0,1)
(0,0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In addition, this feature also exists in the smithchart package already as [is smitchart cs]

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.smithchart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{smithchart}[title=S]
\addplot[is smithchart cs,green] coordinates{
(-1,0)
(1,0)
(0,-1)
(0,1)
(0,0)
};
\end{smithchart}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```